# Overflow exception?

Tags: vb.net, overflow, factorial

I have the following code for finding factorials:

```
Private Shared Function Factorial(ByVal Number As Long) As Long
        If Number = 0 Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return Number * Factorial(Number - 1)
        End If
End Function
```

It usually results in an overflow.  It only works if I start with something small like 4.

I have to work with starting numbers such as 30-60.

Any ideas?  I thought changing the value type to LONG would prevent this problem.

This is VB.net just for reference.

Comment: [30 factorial](http://google.com/search?q=30+factorial) is a **large** number - it won't fit in a Long. You need a BigInteger class for this.

Comment: BTW, "Overflow" and "Stack overflow" are very different exceptions. I assume you are actually getting the former and not the latter.

Comment: Yep, you are right, it was an overflow.  My bad, I'm used to seeing "Stack Overflow" so... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factorials get very large, very quickly. The largest number that will fit in a  `Long` is about 9×10^18. Factorial(30) is about 2.7×10^32.

If you're using .Net 4 there is a built-in [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) class that you can use which will hold arbitrarily large numbers.

If you're not using .Net 4, you'll need to find and download a BigInteger library, for example [intx](http://intx.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You get the overflow exception only with integer and long types. To avoid that, you can use System.Double or System.Numerics.BigInteger (or BigDecimal I think).

For example, 
if you run 3 different versions of the factorial: 1 with long, 1 with double and 1 with biginteger as follow with a range of values of 5 to 50 by 5:

```
    'Long Factorial   
    Public Function FactorialInt64(ByVal n As Integer) As Int64  
        If n = 1 Then  
            Return 1  
        Else  
            Return n * FactorialInt64(n - 1)  
        End If  
    End Function  
    ' Double Factorial   
    Public Function FactorialDouble(ByVal n As Integer) As Double  
        If n = 1 Then  
            Return 1  
        Else  
            Return n * FactorialDouble(n - 1)  
        End If  
    End Function  
    ' BigInteger Factorial   
    Public Function FactorialBigInteger(ByVal n As Integer) As BigInteger  
        If n = 1 Then  
            Return 1  
        Else  
            Return n * FactorialBigInteger(n - 1)  
        End If  
    End Function
```

You will get a result like this:

[image: Factorial execution results]

You can find the complete source code in my blog post: [Factorial and Fibonacci in VB.NET](http://carlosqt.blogspot.com/2011/02/factorial-and-fibonacci-in-vbnet.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a **big int Library for .NET** that will solve your problem. It can manipulate very large number (limited only by your system memory).

Here is the link: http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/