# factorial error vb.net if exceeding a certain range

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code for finding factorial in vb.net

```
Function factorial(ByVal n As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Sum As Integer = 1
    For i = 2 To n
        Sum = Sum * i
    Next i
    factorial = Sum
End Function
```

it gives me an error after n=12. how can I fix?

thanks

Comment: The problem is the Integer data type, which is not large enough to hold big values. Define Sum as ULong to be able to calculate larger values. You may to check this for more information: [Factorial Algorhithms](http://whenimbored.xfx.net/2015/05/factorial-calculation-algorithms/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overflow exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483940/overflow-exception)